# Imprimir com Java com impressora configurada por IP

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Bom precisava resolver um problema que é, como o software vai rodar na nuvem, estava pensando em enviar as informações para a impressora através dela configurada por IP na máquina, eu já configurei ela no Windows mais não achei nenhum exemplo direito na Internet para fazer isso do jeito que eu quero, através de um IP fixo. A alguma maneira de adequar esse código abaixo para fazer isso?

```
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cupomNaoFiscal.getBytes());
        DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        SimpleDoc simpleDoc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, docFlavor, null);
        PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new JobName("Impressão", null));
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A8);
        printRequestAttributeSet.add();

        DocPrintJob docPrintJob = printService.createPrintJob();

        docPrintJob.print(simpleDoc, printRequestAttributeSet);

        inputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```